# clear google console in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console

I want to clear the Google console and I know two ways:
The first one is by use (useEffect).
The second one is by putting the code directly in (return function).
Both ways are shown in the code below, but which one is correct and why?

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./routes/home/Home";
import Navigation from "./routes/navigation/Navigation";
import Authentication from "./routes/authentication/Authentication";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => console.clear(), 1500);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigation />}>
        <Route index={true} element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="auth" element={<Authentication />} />
      </Route>
    {setTimeout(() => console.clear(), 1500)}
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **useEffect** is the correct way. Here is the explanation:

In React, function components has the same life cycle as class components, as you can see in the image below, they load, render and then something called "componentDidMount" is called:

[image]

For code to subscribe, clean, fetch, etc. the optimal way is putting all inside the componentDidMount stage, in function components, this stage is defined as a useEffect without dependencies, as this loads after the component does it's render stage. (you can learn more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Another thing that you can do is using the "componentWillUnmount" stage, this component's stage is called when is about to disappear, as the result of a navigation or something related to that. So, this should work if you want to clear the console every time the user go to other site page.

In function components, this is called the "cleanup" function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        console.clear();
    }
});
```

Hope that helps you :)